# Custom Authentication in Oracle APEX

Tags: oracle, function, authentication, oracle-apex

I created a custom authentication scheme with the table bellow:

[table of users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0DdH.png)

and this function

```
 FUNCTION authenticate(username_in IN VARCHAR2,password_in IN VARCHAR2) RETURN BOOLEAN IS
   l_value       NUMBER;
   l_returnvalue BOOLEAN;
 BEGIN
   BEGIN
     SELECT 1
       INTO l_value
       FROM USERS
      WHERE 1 = 1
        AND upper(users.USERNAME) = upper(username_in)
        AND upper(users.PASSWORD) = upper(password_in);
   EXCEPTION
     WHEN no_data_found
          OR too_many_rows THEN
       l_value := 0;
     WHEN OTHERS THEN
       l_value := 0;
   END;
   l_returnvalue := l_value = 1;
   RETURN l_returnvalue;
 END;
```

When I try to login, I get this error :

> 1 error has occurred line 24, column 23: PLS-00306: wrong number or
>   types of arguments in call to 'AUTHENTICATE' PL/SQL: Statement ignored

Comment: Why do you make passwords case-insensitive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Authentication function can have any name, but it **MUST** have two parameters which **MUST** have the following names:

- p_username
- p_password

You can't name them *any way you want*. So - follow that instruction and it should be OK.